# Обход корпоративного прокси

Tags: proxy, прокси, update, взлом

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, по теме, описанной в заголовке.

Ситуация такова: есть несколько компьютеров, подключённых к роутеру с прошивкой DD-WRT. Куда идёт от роутера кабель - неизвестно. Известно только то, что подключение к интернету происходит через прокси-сервер (скажем, proxy.mycorp.ru:3128). При этом блокируются некоторые порты и протоколы, в том числе NTP и Bittorrent, а также весь windowsupdate.com. Из-за этого не устанавливаются обновления, не синхронизируется время, невозможна загрузка компонентов Windows и много других неприятностей. При этом к компьютерам и роутеру есть полный доступ, с ними можно сделать всё, что угодно, а вот человека, который настраивает сеть в здании, найти практически невозможно :D

Да, и ещё в наличии есть домашний роутер с белым статическим ip, Raspberry Pi и домашний пк. Можно ли как-то настроить всё это для обхода фильтров в организации?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас есть выход в Интернет через прокси-сервер и компьютер, который ждёт вас снаружи, можно обеспечить практически полностью неограниченный выход в Интернет. Множество техник, позволяющих, пользуясь ограниченным выходом в Интернет, расширять его до полноценного, известно под названием *firewall piercing*.

Организовывать выход в Интернет можно даже тогда, когда есть только лишь возможность разрешения DNS-имён (DNS tunneling), проходят одни только пинги (ICMP tunneling) и прочее. Если же есть прокси, то это вообще элементарно.

**Если прокси-сервер позволяет метод CONNECT,** всё делается в два счёта. Обычно метод CONNECT разрешается как минимум для порта 443, но часто и для 80.

В этом случае вы можете для начала организовать выход наружу по SSH.
Используйте программу *corkscrew*.

В конфигурационный файл ssh `~/.ssh/config` прописываете

```
ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy.work.com 80 %h %p
```

После этого:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 user@server.at.home -p 443
```

Здесь вы не только зашли на свой удалённый компьютер по SSH, но ещё заодно и пробросили 80 порт на 8080 локальной машины.

[image: источник: daniel.haxx.se]

*(источник изображения: daniel.haxx.se)*

SSH это очень и очень много, уже практически всё.

Если на компьютере, с которого вы запускаете `ssh` (в нашей терминологии *клиенте*) у вас есть права root'а вы можете не только пробрасывать порты, но и поднять полноценный туннель с маршрутизацией.

Сделать это можно не только с помощью SSH, но и с помощью OpenVPN, VTUN и множества других подобных программ.

В отличие от `ssh` эти программы требуют наличия прав root'а локально. `ssh` даже и без прав root'а позволяет довольно много (кроме создания интерфейсов и маршрутизации через них).

**Если CONNECT на прокси запрещён,** пройти через него тоже можно, но чуть-чуть сложнее. Один из инструментов, позволяющих сделать это, это `httptunnel`.

Используются две программы:

- клиент, `htc`;
- сервер, `hts`.

Сервер вы запускаете дома, клиент на работе:

```
hts -F localhost:22 80
htc -P proxy.corp.com:80 -F 8022 server.at.home:80
```

Здесь вы отфорвардили порт SSH на порт 8022 локально,
а дальше всё как обычно.

Подробнее:

- http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/sshproxy.html (англ.)

Подробнее о вышеупомянутом DNS-tunneling'е (хотя пока у вас не настолько суровые условия):

- http://xgu.ru/wiki/DNS-tunneling (рус.)

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, вы спасли вопрос.

Comment: @VladD: Влад, спасибо! А почему спас вопрос? Что вы хотели сделать с бедным вопросом? Закрыть?

Comment: Ну, вопрос выглядел немного оффтопиком. Но с таким ответом жалко голосовать против.